# New lights turn on very dim

Tags: electrical, lighting, junction-box

I recently installed 2 wafer lights in an existing wiring system. The house is from the 70s, I'm not sure how old the wiring is.

I initially had 2 canned lights. I removed one of them as it had rusted and stopped working but decided to keep the other can intact. I used new wafer lights (in the case where I removed the can, I connected it directly to the 12/2 wire off the junction box and in the case where I had the can installed, I used an E26 adapter to screw the wafer light into the recessed can.

I did not add any additional lighting, just replaced the old lights.
The lights worked fine for about a week or two. However, now, they only turn on really dimly (see picture).

- I checked my connections and everything seems secure.
- I used a voltmeter and checked for voltage with the voltmeter reading ~123V for the light switch as well as the power going to the wafer light (not the retrofitted can one, but the other one).
- I also checked for continuity on the light switch using the voltmeter.
- I even tried using a new wafer light, but same result.

I have shared my wiring diagram along with actual pictures of my J Box and my light fixture. Any idea what I may be doing wrong and how I can fix this issue? Thank you!

[image]

[image: Wafer Light wiring]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thought: Look at the installation instructions for your lights. I've seen some fixtures which have a "night light" dim mode that can be switched into or out of by briefly flipping the switch; it's not impossible that yours have a similar feature and you accidentally put them in that mode.

Comment: why and how have you chose to connect the black and white at some point

Comment: @keshlam - thanks for the suggestion. I double checked, but couldn't find any switch for night mode. What's surprising is that they were working just fine and then just started getting dim all of a sudden

Comment: @Ruskes - that's just how my old wiring was. My guess is they did that due to laziness or to save on running a new wire?

Comment: usually the combo of black and white are used as part of switch loop

Comment: That's right. It is wired as a switch loop. As I mentioned, it is a older home :)

Comment: The signal for night mode may be just "flashing" the light on and off briefly. Again, check the documentation that came with the light to see if this feature exists and how to control it if so. But this is just a guess based on a feature I know exists in some fixtures which is likely to cause confusion; if the documentation doesn't say this mode exists, I'm almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Since they both worked at first, then not so much, I'd suspect a connection become poor. If the wire nuts were not replaced with new ones and double-checked to be securely spiral twisted inside, I'd try that. Since the lights are in parallel, such an issue would not be at one of the light hookups, but rather in the electrical box or switch hookup.

Comment: @Armand - I checked the voltage coming into the light fixture using a voltmeter (between hot and ground) and it was 123V. I'll check on the voltage between the hot and the neutral and report back

Comment: You might also disconnect the hard-wired light and then see if the other light works OK and vice versa.

Comment: Also what model wafer lights are you using? Are they rated for no-ventilation enclosed use in a ceiling? I notice you've got insulation all around the blue box.

Comment: @Armand - I'm using these: https://a.co/d/aPvnLYW
I have these installed in another room (that has insulation around it as well) and it seems to be working well there.
Thanks for the direction on the checks. I'll try to bypass the light switch and see if each of the lights works independently when going straight from line to each of the wafer lights. I'll report back.

Comment: The lights seem to be a no-name Amazon brand, so it may just be the lights themselves failing in some way (although it sounds like a 3rd one is also only dim right from the start, right?) I note that the vendor admitted on the listing that in fact they are not UL listed and the lights are no longer available, so perhaps try a more mainstream brand and see if one of those works in your setup?

Comment: The push-in connectors that came with the lights look sketchy to me; similar "back stab" connectors in cheap light switches are notorious for bad connections, which can be dangerous as well. If you keep these lights, I would definitely cut off the push connectors and just use normal wire nuts.

Comment: Thank you. I will give these suggestions a try and get back with results

Answer (score 1):

Check your quality and polarity of your connections, you probably have a loose termination, which simulates a disconnected neutral 'aka dim glow'. You will need to trace the circuit using a DMM and a flex lead and perform a continuity /ohm test